# Chart.js version 2.2.1 wont show chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've been trying to get Chart.js version 2.2.1 to show a simple chart using the tutorial from another site..
Even with the most basic data nothing will show. If I use the minified version, the version off CDN nada,nothing, zip.

In Brackets version 1.0.2 works fine, but version 2.2.1 comes up with lots of jshint errors.

I even tried it out on JSFiddle and still nothing with the lastest verson.

Being new to javascript I am wondering if there is something obvious that I am missing, otherwise I will continue to just use an older version.

Here is the working code. I have only added the beginning of the Chart.js file.

```
<canvas width="300px" height="300px" id="my-chart"></canvas>
* Chart.js
 * http://chartjs.org/
 * Version: 1.0.2
 *
 * Copyright 2015 Nick Downie
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 */

var pieData = [
   {
      value: 25,
      label: 'Java',
      color: '#811BD6'
   },
   {
      value: 10,
      label: 'Scala',
      color: '#9CBABA'
   },
   {
      value: 30,
      label: 'PHP',
      color: '#D18177'
   },
   {
      value : 35,
      label: 'HTML',
      color: '#6AE128'
   }
];

var context = document.getElementById('my-chart').getContext('2d');
var skillsChart = new Chart(context).Pie(pieData);
```

If I use version 2.2.1 of Chart.js nothing happens.

```
/*!
 * Chart.js
 * http://chartjs.org/
 * Version: 2.2.1
 *
 * Copyright 2016 Nick Downie
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 */
```

Below are fiddles to the two versions

Working [Chart.js version 1.0.2 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/QBob/0293c34w/)

Not working [Chart.js version 2.2.1 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/QBob/8rvkkoav/)

Comment: Well if you don't show what you tried then we wont find the possible errors in it. "I even tried it out on JSFiddle" --> maybe you want to share that with us

Comment: Added links to fiddles as suggested...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax has changed since 1.0. Your javascript in 2.2.1 should be:

```
var data = {
    labels: [
        "Java",
        "Scala",
        "PHP",
        "HTML"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [25, 10, 30, 35],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#811BD6",
                "#9CBABA",
                "#D18177",
                "#6AE128"
            ]
        }]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("my-chart");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'pie',
    data: data
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o1dnyqhz/)

[CHARTJS DOCUMENTATION](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart)

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought I was going mad! Problem was I was trying to use version 2 but following a tutorial for version 1. Again thank you.