# Chart.Js : How to show label into tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js, adminlte

I'm using adminlte 2 default chart js, and when I'm using command in documentation chartjs it's not working in my chart

I've tried to writing label: "Planned" and label: "Done", but it's not showing anywhere

this my chart js code

```
var chartData1 = {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Planned",
            fillColor : "rgba(252, 172, 44,0.0)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(252,172,44,0.8)",
            pointColor: "rgba(252,172,44,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#000",
            pointHighlightFill: "#000",
            data : [1,2,3,4,5]
        },
        {
            label: "Done",
            fillColor : "rgba(102, 204, 255,0.3)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(102, 204, 255,0.8)",
            pointColor: "rgba(102, 204, 255,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#000",
            pointHighlightFill: "#000",
            data : [1,2,3,4,5]
        }
    ]
};
var areaChartOptions = {
      showScale               : true,
      scaleShowGridLines      : true,
      scaleGridLineColor      : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
      scaleGridLineWidth      : 1,
      scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
      scaleShowVerticalLines  : true,
      bezierCurve             : true,
      bezierCurveTension      : 0.5,
      pointDot                : true,
      pointDotRadius          : 4,
      pointDotStrokeWidth     : 1,
      pointHitDetectionRadius : 20,
      datasetStroke           : true,
      datasetStrokeWidth      : 5,
      datasetFill             : true,
      legendTemplate          : '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>',
      maintainAspectRatio     : false,
      responsive              : false,
      showTooltips            : true,
    }
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
var myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData1, areaChartOptions);
```

i'm wanna showing label planned and done to tooltip

[image]

Comment: I see the tooltips when I [try your code here](https://jsfiddle.net/05ua1vqy/). Which version of `chart.js` are you using?

Comment: I don't know I'm using which version, because of that from admin lte 2, but thanks for comment, this library <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.1.1/Chart.min.js"></script> working for me

Comment: It could be that you wrote code based on `chart.js` documentation for version 1 while AdminLTE is using version 2. However, you mentioned that you're using AdminLTE 2, which [uses chart.js v1 in these demos](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/charts/chartjs.html); AdminLTE 3 [seems to use v2](https://adminlte.io/themes/dev/AdminLTE/pages/charts/chartjs.html). In any case, [syntax has changed in version 2](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/). Also see [Chart.js version 2.2.1 wont show chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941528/chart-js-version-2-2-1-wont-show-chart).